# Dataflow job not doing anything after starting workers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

There are no worker logs in a particular environment I am running this pipeline in. Workers are being started but post that it is not being able to do anything and batch pipeline is running for long time. I have set parameters like --subnetwork etc for shared VPC also the worker region is same as shared VPC region.

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal, complete, and reproducible, sample of your code/command where you are seeing the problem. For additional reference, see this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)